# c++, have problems with destructor

Tags: c++, destructor

I have such code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X
{
    int a;
public:
    X()
    {
        cout<<"X constructor was called"<<endl;
    }
    X(int n)
    {
        cout<<"X(int) constructor was called"<<endl;
    }
    ~X(){cout<<"X dectructor was called"<<endl;}
};
int main()
{
    X x(3);

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

The result of this code execution is: X(int) constructor was called . 
But why the destructor message have not been printed?

As I understand, we create object x by calling constructor X(int) and in the end of the program this object have to be deleted, but it did not.

Comment: have you tried to debug and put a break point inside the destructor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's allocated on stack, Destructor should be called here:

```
int main()
{
    X x(3);

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
} // X destructor (x go out of context)
```

Answer (score 2):

The destructor is run when the object goes out of scope. I'm guessing you put `system("pause")` to see its message. Well no, the scope of `x` didn't yet end there, it ends after `return 0;`.

Run your program from the terminal and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor will not be called until the object is out of scope, and **that's not going to happen until you exit main**.

This is why the message doesn't pop up: The console is gone by the time the object is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
int main()
{
    {
       X x(3);
    } // Your x object is being destroyed here

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

It will create a local scope for X, so that you see X being destroyed.